# Point out my fallacy in the three-of-kind problem, please

Tags: combinatorics

**How many hands of three-of-kind are there from a standard 52-card deck?**

$$
13 \binom{4}{3} \binom{12}{2}\binom{4}{1}^2
$$
is the correct answer:

- $13$ :  #ways to choose the denomination of the three-of-a-a-kind
- $\binom{4}{3}$ :  #ways to choose their suits (three-of-a-a-kind);
- $\binom{12}{2}$ :  #ways to choose two distinct denominations for the remaining cards
- $\binom{4}{1}^2$ :  #ways to choose the suits of these latter two.

One could argue that the following is also correct

$$
52 \binom{3}{2} \binom{12}{2} \binom{4}{1}^2
$$

where

- $52$ :  #ways to choose both denomination and suit of the first card in the three-of-a-kind
- $\binom{3}{2}$ :  #ways to choose the suit of the remaining two cards (in the three-of-a-kind)
- $\binom{12}{2} \binom{4}{1}^2$   as before

But 
$$
13 \binom{4}{3} < 52 \binom{3}{2} 
$$
This means that there is an overcounting in the #ways to select the three-of-a-kind.

Can anyone kindly indicate me what I am overcounting? Thank you.

Comment: The "first card" in the three-of-a-kind? What's that?

Comment: "52 ways to choose both denomination and suit **of the first card** in the three-of-a-kind"  And... pray tell... how can you tell which of the three cards in the three of a kind was the "*first*" of them?

Comment: Recall that we can not tell the hands $A\spadesuit A\heartsuit A\diamondsuit 2\spadesuit 3\spadesuit$ and some other arrangement of those cards such as $A\diamondsuit 3\spadesuit 2\spadesuit A\spadesuit A\heartsuit$ apart from one another (*assuming we don't care about order of cards.  If we did care about order of cards, then both answers are wrong*)

Comment: You could have noted $$3\times 13 \binom{4}{3} = 52 \binom{3}{2}.$$  Then the question becomes "where did I triple-count?  As the other comments have indicated, you would have the same hand as long as one of the three cards in the three-of-a-kind was chosen as the first card.

Answer (score 3):

The $52 {3 \choose 2}$ counts each three of a kind three times.  It counts each three of a kind once for having each of the three cards first.  And in fact $52 {3 \choose 2}=3 \cdot \left(13 {4 \choose 3}\right)$